# SQL ' ' do not get escaped

Tags: sql-server, escaping

I am trying to run a query in SQL 2008 by doing:

```
@query varchar(max)

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ' 'Karl' ' '

EXEC(@query)
```

The problem is that for some reason the apostrophes around `'Karl'` don't get escaped, i.e. the query executes as `...WHERE [Name] = Karl` and fails.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2008, right?  Not MySQL or PostgreSQL or SQLite or any of the other variants of SQL?

Comment: What do you see if you print the string @query?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways that you can escape character data in SQL Server, some people even advocate the use of the [QUOTENAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) functions.

If you really want to develop of solid understanding of this subject area then may I recommend that you take a look at what experienced SQL Server Developers consider to be essential reading with regard to the different methods you can use to incorporate Dynamic T-SQL into your coding.

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 2):

This works on my machine from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
@query varchar(max)

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ''''''Karl'''''''

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: this will not work, unless Karl is stored in the database with two single quotes before and after his name like ''Karl'' because it results in the actual query being: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = '''Karl'''

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max)

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ''Karl'''

PRINT 'when in doubt, print the query out: '+ISNULL(@query,'')
EXEC(@query)
```

To have a single quote appear, you need to have two adjacent single quotes.  You escape a single quote with a single quote, for example:

```
PRINT ''''     --will print a one single quote
PRINT ''''''   --will print two single quotes
PRINT 'can''t' --will print can't
```

Answer (score 1):

A double single ('') quote will act like a single single quote when inside a string literal.

Have you tried using a variable?

```
declare @karl_name varchar(10);
set @karl_name = '''Karl''';

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = @karl_name
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this 
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ''''Karl'''''

Comment: this will not work, unless Karl is stored in the database with one single quote before and after his name like 'Karl' because it results in the actual query being: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ''Karl''

Comment: thne add one more Quote at the end
do like this SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ''''Karl'''''' like this

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
create table #demo([Name] varchar(max))
insert into #demo([Name]) values('''Karl''')
insert into #demo([Name]) values('Karl')
declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = 'SELECT * FROM #demo WHERE [Name] = ''''''Karl'''''''
EXEC(@query)
```

Output:

```
'Karl'
```

But if 'Karl' is variable text, it's highly recommended to use something like this instead:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @param varchar(max)
set @param = N'''Karl'''
set @query = N'SELECT * FROM #demo WHERE [Name] = @param'
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@param varchar(max)', @param
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply escape the apostrophes by using the escaping bar \ like this  'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Name] = ' \'Karl\' ' '

Hope it helps